# change output format of git diff depending on length of difference

Tags: regex, git, diff, git-diff

I've recently discovered the `--color-words` option to `git diff` and in many cases it makes reading diffs easier, eg when only a word or two on a line are changed. However, when a significant portion of a line is changed, it becomes harder to see the change because the added and deleted lines aren't nicely stacked on top of each other.

Is it possible for git diff to switch which output mode it uses "on the fly" based on the length of the delta, perhaps by making clever use of the `--word-diff-regex` option?

Comment: Can you share an example?

Comment: @SahilGulati [here](https://gist.github.com/rpatel3001/705c7cd17b8dbe29602c2c115185622a)

notice the changes in the first and last lines are more readable, but the middle line is unwieldy, especially as the length of the line gets longer

Comment: Do you want result in this format? https://regex101.com/r/uPXPE6/1

Comment: @SahilGulati like that but without repeated the lines with short changes, I've update the gist to illustrate